# Paso y recepcion de variables por GET [PHP]

Tags: php, javascript, .htaccess, get

No puedo recoger mi variable $_GET correctamente.

Tengo un boton que a traves de javascript me redirige a una url

```
$(".btnSeeGlossary").click(function() {
    let idGlossary = $(this).attr("idGlossary");


    window.location = "glossary?id=" + idGlossary;


})
```

Una vez redirigido, digamos que la url quedo `http://localhost/translateapp/glossary?id=6`, estoy en el sitio maquetado, quiero obtener el id de la siguiente manera:

```
$value = $_GET["id"];
var_dump($value);
```

> Var dump me retorna NULL =(

Si cambio por

```
$value = $_GET;
var_dump($value);
```

> Value retorna "glossary"
>
> Edit: Dejo el htaccess por si esto pueda estar afectando.

```
Options All -Indexes 

RewriteEngine On 

RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?route=$1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Finalmente, era el `htaccess`. Si reescribo las url debo agregar la bandera `[QSA]`

```
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?route=$1 [QSA]
```

solucionó el problema.